# How can I get a snapshot view from an event-based table in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

On MariaDB I have an orders table where I can have multiple records with the same order id, referring to events in the order lifecycle.
I need to extract a list of all orders that have not reached a "completed" state, meaning there is no record with that order id and state=completed.

So if I have the following records

```
Order Id | State
---------|---------
1        | new
2        | new
3        | new
1        | updated
2        | completed
1        | completed
4        | new
4        | updated
```

I would expect to get as a result orders 3 and 4

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result. (E.g. do you want just the order id's, or the whole rows.)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to extract a list of all orders that have not reached a "completed" state, meaning there is no record with that order id and state=completed.

Use aggregation like this:

```
select ol.order_id
from order_lifecycle ol
group by ol.order_id
having sum(ol.state = 'completed') = 0;
```

The expression `state = 'completed'` counts the number of rows where `state = 'completed'` for each order.  The `= 0` says that there are not any.

If you have a separate table of orders, you might find it faster to use `not exists`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where not exists (select 1
                  from order_lifecycle ol
                  where ol.order_id = o.order_id and
                        ol.state = 'completed'
                 );
```

This can, in particular, take advantage of an index on `order_lifecycle(order_id, state)`.